# How to Have Minecraft Command Blocks output comparator signal in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have command blocks behave as if they were executing the old /testfor command, whereas if what it's testing for is true, it allows comparators to output a signal. Or, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I'm leaning towards rolling this back, as you got an answer prior to your edit. You can always ask another question for your new one.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.9 and after, you can click on the command block and click `Unconditional` to change it to a conditional command block. The way those work is if the previous command block returns something that is not `null`, then the conditional command block will then run its command.
So say you have an `execute` command that runs an `if` command, and another command that is set to `Conditional`. If the `if` command returns `true`, then the rest of the `execute` command will run and the conditional command block will run, but if the `if` command returns `false`, then the `execute` command will quit, and the game will move on to the next *unconditional* command block, which means that the conditional command block will not run.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The way that was already recommended for a long time is using `/execute` to execute commands based on the conditions you want. `/execute` also has a lot of other features, like executing commands in other locations, from other entities, etc.